# Convert historical tables to use range date (from and to date) instead of snapshot date

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want this to be done within a simple SQL select statement without any functions that are exclusive to that environment(derived queries, common table expressions, temp tables INSERT, UPDATE statements are okay). Check my tags at the end of the post to understand why.

Reference me any issue that has it. I couldn't find a title that is clear as mine with results in stackoverflow.

Example of use case
Original Table: history_table_snapshot

```
Value|Date
50   |01
50   |02
24   |03
50   |04
```

Converted Table: history_table_range

```
Value|DateStart|DateEnd
50   |01       |03
24   |03       |04
50   |04       |infinity
```

Also, make this query handle other complicated/high scale use cases (i.e. 50 columns within the historical table with the possibility of some column except the primary keys to be null)

Comment: Does Amazon Redshift have `lead()` and `lag()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Yes, it does.

Comment: Edited the values of the converted table. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lag` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE history_table_range
(Value, DateStart, DateEnd)
AS 
SELECT Value, Date, LAG (DATE) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC)
```

EDIT:
As Gordon Linoff noted in the comments, just using `lead` would be much cleaner:

```
CREATE TABLE history_table_range
(Value, DateStart, DateEnd)
AS 
SELECT Value, Date, LEAD (DATE) OVER (ORDER BY date)
```

Comment: I find this funny.  Is there a reason you didn't do:  `lead(date) over (order by date)`?

Comment: I started out with `lag`, ran the query, and discovered I had the order reversed. As you noted - just replacing `lag` with `lead` would have made much more sense. What an annoying example of [perceptual blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness).

Comment: A more clean option would be first_value and last_value instead of lead or lag that are designed for offset calculation.

Comment: The query above does not give the results as the converted table output.

https://gist.github.com/asokratis/c16fc4fcfb75fb7539e5

Comment: I have to add that this will definitely solve my problem and will use it as a solution for now.

The way snapshot tables are consumed in a lot of business cases by design is in such a way that it uploads a new record even if the values haven't changed.

I hope I can see an answer where the converted table normalizes the data itself too.

Comment: Referenced my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019430/sql-segmenting-values-within-a-local-scope-of-time as this can be a more generic problem. Thanks for the help